# "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags" in React/Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have a React/Electron app that I'm building on & for Windows with `electron-builder`. It builds fine, but when I try to run the packaged program I get

```
Uncaught Exception:
C:\My Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\build\electron.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global, Buffer) { return function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /home/jd/projects/app/src/start.js
                                                                                                                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:660:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:704:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\My Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js:188:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\My Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js:190:3)
```

I'm trying to make sense of this. I've unpacked `electron.asar` to look at `init.js`, which has 189 lines (?) and line 188 is

```
Module._load(path.join(packagePath, mainStartupScript), Module, true)
```

This seems like it's something happening in Electron, outside of the app I've written being called? This looks like an error before it even gets to my main `start.js` for React.

Appreciate any thoughts on how I can go about debugging this, please let me know if there's any more useful information I can include.

**EDIT**: Of course I should have mentioned, I don't use any regex anywhere in my app.

**EDIT 2**: I've uploaded my package.json to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jdrusso/a1256ba0386a1ce06e9bee521158d55a)

**EDIT 3**: This project was bootstrapped with `create-react-app`

Comment: Do you have any regex in your application?

Comment: @Rockey Nope, I don’t. Added that to the post.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5564 and see if it applies to you

Comment: @Rockey Thanks for the link! Unfortunately I’d come across that, and I’m not using Babili.

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint with only the error output. It appears to be a problem with the build script injecting file paths. `/home/` is being interpreted as regex with invalid flags of `jd/projects/app/src/start.js`. May need to provide your package.json for people to replicate

Comment: @Lex Thanks! That gets me a little closer to understanding the error message itself. I've added my package.json to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jdrusso/a1256ba0386a1ce06e9bee521158d55a). Based on what you're saying, it seems like somewhere a pair of quotes may be missing and that path is getting pulled as a regex instead of a string?

Comment: I added to the main post that I bootstrapped with create-react-app, so I wonder if in the internal webpack/babel config within that, this path is being improperly escaped, leading to it being read as a regex instead of a string.

Comment: Hmmm I haven't used electron. In your package.json you're using `react-scripts build` to build you may want to `electron-builder`. Perhaps try creating an electron app using their demo project and adding react to it as a dependancy.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, there is text that is interpreted as a regular expression.

Looking at the error message you pasted, you can see that the file `C:\My Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\build\electron.js` starts correctly and they contains the string `/home/jd/projects/app/src/start.js`.

I think that `/home/jd` is parsed as a regular expression with the flags `jd`, although the only valid flags are `gimuy` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2)).

My advice would be that you clean your build directory `C:\My Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\build\` and try to compile again, although I have no idea how the string `/home/jd/projects/app/src/start.js` appeared in your built asset. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've managed to sort of get around it in a crappy way by just `npm run eject`ing it, but like you said, I'm trying to hunt down why that string is being sent somewhere unescaped in the first place! Appreciate the tips